# Какие надежные системы защиты от взлома защиты программ существуют?

Tags: защита, reverse-engineering

Какие надежные системы защиты от взлома защиты программ существуют? В частности, от реверс инженеринга?

Слышал краем уха про защиту на основе выполнения кода в самописных виртуальных машинах.

Кто что знает на этот счет?

Comment: Если что-то можно запустить, это что-то можно и взломать.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под защитой? Защита чего? От копирования, защита алгоритма, пароля, доступа или что? Поточнее пожалуйста

Answer (score 6, accepted):

100% надежных систем от взлома нет. Другой вопрос, что возможно имеет смысл сделать так, чтобы программную системы было бессмысленно взламывать.

Существует множество трюков, предназначенных для защиты программы от взлома:

- программы-упаковщики. Они упаковывают исполняемый файл, причем иногда весьма причудливыми способами.
- программы-протекторы. Они зачастую пакуют исполняемый код программы + всячески перерабатывают его: изменяют таблицы импорта и расположение модулей исполняемого файла, добавляют вызовы левого кода, зашифровывают код, использование [самомодифицирующегося кода](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/277/277r.shtml) и пр.
- программы-обфускаторы. Они добавляют лишних код, переименовывают переменные и ф-ции (в случае, например, платформы .net, где распространяется промежуточный байт-код, а не исполнимые файлы под конкретную машину)
- антиотладочные приемы. Примеры: [1](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/073/073r.shtml), [2](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/296/296r.shtml)
- написать свою виртуальную машину (а спецификации никому не давать :-)) и написать программу под нее.

Возможно использование всяких привязок к аппаратной части ПК.

В конечном счете, стоимость защиты не должна превосходить стоимость защищаемого =)

Answer (score 8):

OpenSource. Если все открыто, то кто будет взламывать? Make love not war.

Это шутка, конечно. Тут такая же ситуация, как и с железной дверью. Все эти шифрования, обфускаторы и пр. - защита от шпаны. Серьезных специалистов это не остановит. Замедлит, конечно, их действия, но все равно взломают.

Answer (score 3):

Лицензионное соглашение + юристы.

Не стоит заморачиваться на всяких обфускаторах. Кому надо - тот и обфусцированный код восстановит. и самописную виртуалку поломает.

Пишите качественный софт, за который людям будет хотеться заплатить.

Comment: Поставил плюс исключая первое предложение.

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает лицензионное соглашение?) В случае его нарушения можно будет схватить за промежности нарушителя. Юристыпомогут)

Comment: Я считаю, что ловить кого-то за промежности имеет право только тот, кто сам не пользуется пиратской продукцией (любой). У Вас все программы, музыка, видео и пр. лицензионные?

Comment: @mikillskegg, если б у меня, как у разраба, была возможность продавать свой софт (без штата юристов и СБ с дубинками), у меня бы абсолютно все было лицензионное. А еще я бы делал бесплатный и (AND, а не XOR) качественный софт в свободное время. И меня печалит, что это не так. И да, я осознаю: то, что я в замкнутом кругу - это хорошее объяснение, но плохое оправдание.

Comment: @mikillskegg у меня - да)
Я ж линуксоид)
Из платного софта пользуюсь триальными версиями. Если софт нравится, и от него есть практический толк - покупаю.

Comment: `В случае его нарушения можно будет схватить за промежности нарушителя` – если, конечно, вы 1) узнаете о взломе и 2) опознаете совершившего его. Хотя, именно благодаря таким как вы у нас в юности появилась возможность пользоваться такими прекрасными программными пакетами, как Windows, Photoshop и даже 3DS Max.

Answer (score 3):

Неплохой вариант, но требующий подключения к инету у юзера - перекладывание логики на сервер.

Т.о. ломать софт бесполезно, ибо он по сути чистый view (получить, показать, отправить запрос). Кейгены бесполезны - код проверяется на серваке, дебаг, кряки - туда же. По приколу можно, конечно, и обфускатором пройтись со всякими антидебагами, чтоб совсем кровь из глаз.

Но применим способ только если первое условие не критично.

Answer (score 2):

Вот список в произвольном порядке:

[VMProtect](http://vmpsoft.com/)
[Armadillo](http://www.siliconrealms.com/)
[Asprotect](http://www.aspack.com/asprotect.html)