# Как защитить Golang код?

Tags: golang, безопасность, дизассемблирование

Сейчас порылся в OllyDBG, нашел всю свою структуру кода что и какой файл, все зависимо-импортируемые либы, что какие и где файлы создаются (их путь), мои `структуры, мапы, функции` половину видно точно в форме **ACSII текста**, я не говорю про прямой ассемблер я просто офигел...

Такое чувство будто я сейчас не в диззасемблер смотрю, а в свою ***Visual Studio Code***, все функции, каллбеки, системные вызовы что куда передается, где какой файл создается, где какой путь в реестре создается.. и так просто передаются ввиде **ACSII текста**... Это же если ещё и кто-то грамотный в диззасемблировании откроет мое приложение, так это считай просто отдал свой исходный код.

Как мне намного надежнее защитить свой исходный код, обфускаторов для Golang не знаю да и они значительно ухудшат производительность Golang кода, а мне ооочень важна производительность?

UPD: Компилировал с флагами "-w -s", а потом закинул в UPX

Comment: `strip -s` вам в помощь.

Comment: @Ainar-G обновил тему, забыл добавить что всё это я компилировал под -w -s флагаи, а далее закинул под UPX

Comment: это Вы ещё кода на java/C# не видели. Там иногда почти полностью автоматически проект восстанавливают.

Comment: @KoVadim ну это понятно, но мы же сейчас говорим про компилированный многопоточный ЯП со статической/динамической линковкой, кстати о статической линковке, я использую модуль sqlite3, но он не поддерживает статическую линковку, поэтому я не могу скомпилировать со статической линковкой, но я думаю что если бы я использовал статичекую линковку у меня бы столько моих данных не отобразило, а было бы в виде ассемблер кода

Comment: Если не нравится, что делает компилятор - напишите свой. Кому нужно - все может посмотреть и потрогать. А остальным оно не нужно/не по силам

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Какие надежные системы защиты от взлома защиты программ существуют?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/162105/Какие-надежные-системы-защиты-от-взлома-защиты-программ-существуют)

Answer (score 1):

Никак! OllyDBG и radare всегда помогут в том, чтобы увидеть как работает говнокод! Главное - уметь пользоваться этими инструментами. Обфускация вообще не поможет. Ну, или поможет, но не так сильно, как хотелось бы.